# deserializing JSON object .net

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have problem with deserialize json object. I read many threads on stackoverflow but I didn't find solution. I use .net 2.0 and Newtonsoft library.

Below is json string:

```
{
    "data": {
        "custom_fields": [{
            "field": "segmentid",
            "value": "B"
        },
        {
            "field": "subsegmentid",
            "value": "TM3"
        },
        {
            "field": "contactpersonid",
            "value": "000187_003"
        },
        {
            "field": "firstname",
            "value": "ZBIGNIEW"
        },
        {
            "field": "agreetment",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "field": "contactname",
            "value": "ZBIGNIEW TESTOWY"
        },
        {
            "field": "decisionmaking",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "field": "lastpurchase",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "field": "agethresholds",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "field": "tendercust",
            "value": ""
        }],
        "email": "myself@example.com",
        "state": "1"
    },
    "status": "OK"
}
```

I developed two classes but I still get below error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FMIntegration.DataFM]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'data.email'

```
var SubscriberGet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubscriberGet>(json); 

public class SubscriberGet
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<DataFM> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataFM
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_fields")]
    public List<String> custom_fields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Custom fields is not a list of strings.

Comment: See what this site (http://json2csharp.com/) generates for you.

Answer (score 4):

Custom fields is not a list of strings but a list of "field and value" pair.

Try this:

```
public class SubscriberGet
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<DataFM> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataFM
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_fields")]
    public List<CustomField> custom_fields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
public class CustomField
{
    [JsonProperty("field")]
    public string field { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct objects to handle my json string (thanks L.B. for link)

```
public class CustomField
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<CustomField> custom_fields { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should award user1477388 the answer as he specified just that. No need to create an identical answer.

Comment: jgauffin: if you read answers one again (carefully) you will see differences. user1477388 codes doesn't work.